# Why are the only avaliable values in propositional logic true or false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

What would propositional logic lose if there were a third value?
Why was it made so it would only have true or false as values?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic

Comment: Read also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle

Comment: In fact there is [Three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), but so called Classical Logic (the bivalent one) is so traditional and common in mathematics and everyday thinking that it is considered "the" logic.

Comment: Other logics turned out to be useless. The law of the exluded middle is too important to omit it.

Comment: Propositions like : "this sentence is false" are neither true nor false, whereas "this sentence is true" are both true and false, so there would exist 4 logical values. These cases are pathological, but they question the basic principles of asserting a two valued logic.

Comment: @Cretin2, rather than showing that there exist 4 logical values that shows that the naive idea that every sentence has a truth value is simply non-tenable.

Comment: Yes and I made a mistake since "This sentence is true" were true then it says from itself it is true, but if it were assumed to be wrong then it would say from itself it is wrong which has no logical value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only true and false leads to a straightforward theory which serves as an adequate foundation for mathematics. If you want other values you're going to have to be more specific about what kind of other values you want and why. Historically they haven't turned out to be useful enough to be worth the bother.

Sometimes some people want to assign third values like "meaningless" to statements like the [liar's paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/) statement "this statement is false." This does not in any way resolve the liar's paradox, because it can trivially be modified to "this statement is not true," which is still paradoxical no matter how many additional truth values there are. (A meaningless statement is in particular not true, so if this statement were meaningless then it would not be true, so it would be true, so...)

This is known as the "revenge problem" and it is very difficult to circumvent. In any case this isn't a big problem for mathematics in practice, e.g. because [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) simply prevents us from stating the liar's paradox in its usual form in first-order logic.